# How should I structure my TCL code?

Tags: tcl

Im new to TCl-facing some problems learning it.

However I need to know if any one of you have some script or any idea so that I could make my code more structured ie more readable

Answer (score 5):

Personally I would recommend [this](http://www.wjduquette.com/tcl/namespaces.html) and [this](http://www.wjduquette.com/tcl/objects.html) articles by [Will Duquette](http://www.wjduquette.com/tcl/index.html), if we're talking about "plain" Tcl (that is, not armed with any extensions aimed at better structuring).

You can do object orientation with Tcl, too. Tcl 8.6 will be equipped with a core OO package, but there is [a whole lot of readily available OO frameworks](http://wiki.tcl.tk/970). Personally, I've successfully used [Snit](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3963) as a plain Tcl OO system.

Comment: +1: The first link, on “Namespaces and Packages”, is particularly good.

Comment: But the link to the Style Guide is broken, it can now be found at http://www.tcl.tk/doc/styleGuide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

[This "***TCL for Web Nerds***"](http://philip.greenspun.com/tcl/) book by Philip Greenspun is very easy to read, and while it's a bit dated, is a great introduction to TCL (especially if you're doing any web programming). I still refer to it occasionally along with the TCL [manuals](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm) and the [Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/) (although to be honest I often the wiki too obscure for many of my needs).

Answer (score 0):

Except for @kostix excellent "advanced" answer, take these basic Tcl beginner tips into account:

- avoid the global top level for writing your code, pack in into Proc-edures
- avoid global variables and use namespaces (see answer @kostix)
- learn about upvar to pass variables by reference
- read other tcl code examples by other experienced tcl users